# Почему в цикле for in не получается сделать так?

Tags: javascript

Почему в цикле for in нельзя получить доступ к значениям свойств объекта через точечную запись, как я показал в первом примере? (вернее можно, но только в таком случае возвращает не значение свойства, а undefined). Почему обязательно нужно использовать квадратные скобки?

```js
let newObject = {
  property1: 'Gohsa',
  property2: 123124,
  proprety3: false
}
console.log('Вариант 1')
for (const key in newObject) {
  console.log(key, newObject.key)
}

newObject = {
  property1: 'Gohsa',
  property2: 123124,
  proprety3: false
}
console.log('Вариант 2')
for (const key in newObject) {
  console.log(key, newObject[key])
}
```

Comment: Потому что интерпретатор воспринимает `newObject.key` как обращение к свойству `key` объекта `newObject`, которого у этого объекта нет, поэтому и возвращается `undefined`. Поэтому необходимо это делать через квадратные скобки